# androidで縦書き

Tags: android

androidで文章を縦書き表示したいのですが、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そもそも縦書き用のフォントが入ってないため、「ー」や「。」の位置を調整したり回転させたりする必要があって面倒です。

githubにライブラリを公開しました。

https://github.com/taizan/vjap

対応機能
-ページスクロールバー
-ページ送りのフリップ/クリック切り替え
-挿絵の表示
-改行時の禁則処理
-ルビ振り
-文字フォント変更（デフォルトフォントとIPA明朝フォントに対応）
-文字サイズ変更
-文字色変更

Answer (score 0):

WebViewを使ってCSSで`-webkit-writing-mode:vertical-rl;`を指定するのが簡単ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 簡単さの面では圧倒的にwebviewの方が楽ですが、フリックと組み合わせたり、禁則処理を実現するのが困難なんですよね。
canvasにごりごり書いていく処理は面倒な人も多いと思うので簡単に仕えるようライブラリしました。